# Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'id<ProtocolName>'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode9, xcode9.3

I want to update XCode version.

But while updating I receive several compiler errors. The are the same as this:

`id<MyProtocol> objectToDelete = group[index.unsignedIntegerValue];`

> Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'id'

`id<MyProtocol> _Nonnull group`

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString* name;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString* id;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString* internalType;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray<id<SomeAnotherProtocol>>* objects;

- (instancetype)initWithObject:(MyProtocol*)object;
// Search
- (BOOL)isContainsObjectWithID:(NSString*)myID;
- (NSUInteger)indexForObjectID:(NSString*)myID;
- (id<SomeAnotherProtocol>)objectWithID:(NSString*)myID;
- (NSString*)groupID;

@end
```

This error appears only on XCode 9.3 version.

Does `id<MyProtocol> objectToDelete = ((NSArray *) group)[index.unsignedIntegerValue];` the only solution?

Comment: `id<MyProtocol> objectToDelete = [group objectAtIndex:index.unsignedIntegerValue];` might do the trick too.

Comment: @Larme `No known instance method for selector 'objectAtIndex:'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm assuming that `group` is not actually an `NSArray`, but is in fact:

```
id<MyProtocol> _Nonnull group
```

This says that `group` is "some object that conforms to `MyProtocol`". Nothing in `MyProtocol` says that this object can be subscripted. If you want it to be subscriptable by indexes, then you need to say this in the protocol:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
- (id<MyProtocol>)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
...
```

And you of course need to implement `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` in anything that conforms (but this seems to already be the case, since it works when you cast it).

Answer (score -1):

try this one:
[group objectAtIndexedSubscript:idx]

Comment: Care to add any information on why the poster should try that one?

Comment: because his project worked with xcode 9.2, but failed with xcode 9.3.
So if `group[...]` works, and `objectAtIndex:index` failes,
I suggest, that somewhere object `group` implements `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` method.